# How to display data from drop down menu into text inputs

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am having trouble displaying the `SessionName`, `SessionDate` and `SessionTime` in their respective text inputs.

What should happen is that the user is suppose to select a Session (Assessment) from the drop down menu. Now when they submit the drop down menu, the details of the Session which are `SessionName`, `SessionDate` and `SessionTime`, should be displayed in their text inputs. But they are not being displayed in their text inputs, the text inputs remain empty.

How can I get the `SessionName`, `SessionTime` and `SessionDate` to be displayed in their respective text inputs?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypcpe/5/) which contains dummy data and relevant features to show what the application should look like:

**Here is my code:**

```
$sessionquery = "
SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
FROM Session
WHERE
(ModuleId = ?)
ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modules']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

$sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

if($sessionnum ==0){
echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</p>";
} else { 

$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbSessionDate, $dbSessionTime) . PHP_EOL;  
}

$sessionHTML .= '</select>';

$assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' onsubmit='return sessionvalidation();'>
<p>Assessments: {$sessionHTML} </p>
<p><input id='sessionSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit Assessment' name='sessionSubmit' /></p>  
<div id='sessionAlert'></div>    
</form>";

echo $assessmentform;

}

}

 if (isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) {

$currentsession = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
<p>Current Assessment's Date/Start Time:</p>
<p>Assessment: <input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionName}'/> </p>
<p>Date: <input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionDate}'/> </p>
<p>Start Time: <input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionTime}'/> </p>
<input type='hidden' id='hiddenId' name='hiddenAssessment' value='{$dbSessionId}'/>
</form>
";  

echo $currentsession;

    }
```

Comment: Since you have tagged `javascript` also, should the values come into the inputs client-side or do you plan to submit the form each time a `change` event occurs in the select? Also, what freebird said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery is an option (and you might feel at some point that the `button` is not needed), here's another option

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#sessions').change( function(){
        if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
            var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            var split = text.split(' - ');
            $('#currentAssessment').val( split[0] );     
            $('#currentDate').val( split[1] );     
            $('#currentTime').val( split[2] );     
        }
        else{
            $('#currentAssessment,#currentDate,#currentTime').val('');                  
        }
    });
});​
```

It works on `.change()` event of the `select` I have edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypcpe/13/) to display it.

Comment: Great answer, I like the onchange method, it gets things done much quicker than the user always clicking on the submit button to choose a session. For this reason I am giving you best answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Ypcpe/9/)**

```
function fillData(){
var sel = document.getElementById('sessions').options[document.getElementById('sessions').selectedIndex].text;
var arr = sel.split(" - ");
 if(document.getElementById('sessions').value != ''){
    document.getElementById('currentAssessment').value = arr[0];
    document.getElementById('currentDate').value = arr[1];
    document.getElementById('currentTime').value = arr[2];                     
 } else {
    alert('please select option');
 }
}​

<p><input id='sessionSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit Assessment' name='sessionSubmit' onclick='fillData();' /></p>
```

Comment: Great answer. It works well. Only reason I am giving Abhilash the best answer is because he got it working with.onchange() which is something I did not think of to be honest and something I liked. So I am giving you upvote for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function SessionSplit()
{
 str=$("#sessions option:selected").text();
 substr=str.split(' - ');
 sessionname=substr[0];
 sessiondate=substr[1];
 sessiontime=substr[2];

}

$('#sessionSubmit').click(function(){

$('#currentAssessment').val(sessionname);
    $('#currentDate').val(sessiondate);
    $('#currentTime').val(sessiontime);

});
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypcpe/14/)**

Comment: Great answer. It works well. Only reason I am giving Abhilash the best answer is because he got it working with .onchange() which is something I did not think of to be honest but something I liked. So I am giving you upvote for your answer :)